# Django Mezzanine - Simple custom Admin Form

Tags: django, forms, admin, mezzanine

I need to add job offers section to my company site (as a intro to django for me). The problem is that when i inherit my model from mezzanine's Page model it adds to admins create form all bunch of field which i dont need (like publish dates, draft field, comment field etc). I want to make create/edit job offers form as simple as possible. 
I tried to inherit it from basic models.Model but it throws an error ...

```
Unknown column 'project_joboffer.id' in 'field list'"
```

I tried to customize Admin Form but im still getting error above.

**models.py**

```
class JobOffer(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
place = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
content = models.TextField(blank=False,null=False)
published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
deleted = models.NullBooleanField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from ckeditor.widgets import CKEditorWidget
from models import JobOffer

class JobOfferForm(forms.ModelForm):
   title = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
   place = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=False)
   content = forms.CharField(required=True , widget=CKEditorWidget())
   published = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)
   deleted = forms.NullBooleanField()
   # class Meta:
   #     model = JobOffer
```

**admin.py**

```
class JobOfferAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   form = JobOfferForm

admin.site.register(JobOffer, JobOfferAdmin)
```

Comment: did you do `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate` ?

Comment: Yes, i do it every time when i make some changes in model or forms. I suspect that mezzanine's default admin forms expect some different name for id field (and maybe other fields) than default model provide.

Answer (score 0):

OK, i fixed it. Migrations creating and deleting wasnt enough. I dont know why but this time i had to also delete entry in django_migrations table.